# Disable modification of assets title and name

Tags: assets, control-panel, permissions

I want to disable the modification of both the file name and title of a specific asset type.
How can I do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this feature request will solve my problem... in the future:
http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7197199-ability-to-hide-or-disable-fields-based-on-a-user

But in the meantime I did it with a small css hacking (no choice):

`protected function includeResources()`

```
switch ( $segments[ 0 ] ) {
    case 'entries' : case 'categories' : case 'assets' :
        craft()->templates->includeCssResource( 'plugin/styles.css' );
        break;
}
```

`style.css`

```
// remove title and name fields from modal editor in CP assets page
    .hud {
        .body.elementeditor {
            .field[id$="filename-field"], .field[id$="-title-field"] {
                display: none;
            }
            .field {
                margin-top: 0px;
            }
        }
    }
```

Works fine :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the capacity to upload, remove, or create subfolders for assets to whomever you wish through the users control panel.

You could potentially solve this problem by limiting the users control to allow them only to upload and not change folders or delete. (see image below)

[image: Craft User Limitation]

Comment: No those permissions are not precise enough in my case. I just want to disable name and title fields.

Comment: hmm, really sorry wouldn't know then :/ ... Maybe there is some kind of plug-in that could help here.

Comment: Right I am making it indeed :D

Comment: Awesome, goodluck my friend!